# Model Associations in Rails Has_many and Belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, associations

Menu Item

```
class MenuItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :menu_tags
end
```

Menu Tags

```
class MenuTag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :menu_item
end
```

Migrations:

```
class CreateMenuItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :menu_items do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :description
    end
  end
end


class CreateMenuTags < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :menu_tags do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.integer :menu_item_id

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

How can I alter this migration so if I run a query for a Menu Item, I can see all the Menu Tags associated with it? Desired query:

```
MenuItem.first = #<MenuItem id: 2, name: "Steak", description: "Shank, medium-rare", menu_tags = [#<MenuTag id: 1, name: "Spicy">, #<MenuTag id: 4, name: "Salty">], created_at: "2016-07-18 02:54:55", updated_at: "2016-07-18 02:54:55">
```

Comment: `MenuItem.joins(:Menutag).all` try this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Already with ActiveRecord, you can see all of the associated models by calling something like:

```
MenuItem.first.menu_tags
```

Problem is, with the above, the database query may not be efficient enough. To solve these ActiveRecord provides methods to eager_load the associations:

```
MenuItem.includes(:menu_tags).first.menu_tags
```

This is more efficient from an ActiveRecord/Database perspective.

One thing you'd quickly observe is that the associated model is not shown in your console when you call:

```
MenuItem.first = #<MenuItem id: 2, name: "Steak", description: "Shank, medium-rare", menu_tags = [#<MenuTag id: 1, name: "Spicy">, #<MenuTag id: 4, name: "Salty">], created_at: "2016-07-18 02:54:55", updated_at: "2016-07-18 02:54:55">
```

This is because the default behaviour of the ActiveRecord#inspect method is to show the properties of the model, without adding those of the associated models. You can [look this up in the source code here..](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/core.rb#L486)

Note: You can define your own behaviour by overriding this inpect method to include the associated objects.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for the explanation! That helped me tremendously!